# Creating a margin while background image having z-index and overlay not affecting the navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar, margin, footer

I am trying to create a web page where I have a margin of 50px fixed left and right where the page images have an index that makes it closer to the screen and the margin looks farther off.I also want to achieve a fixed footer like I have for the navigation bar.I tried setting margin left and right to 50px and setting them to a fixed position and tried using the wrapper class to add to the sections both did not yield desired result.

[image: The margin in the image is what I am trying to achieve]
Here is my code below

**HTML CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Archers</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="arch.css">
</head>

<body>



    <section id="main">
        <div class="bg1">
          <header>
            <div id="navbar">
              <nav class="nav-list">
                <ul class="ul-style ">
                  <li><a href="#portfolio">OUR PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#process">OUR PROCESS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#main">HOME</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </header>
        </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="about">
        <div class="bg1">
          <div class="about_us">
            <a name="#about">
              <p>
                <h1>ABOUT US</h1>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ducimus officia vero, animi dicta magni tenetur praesentium quisquam, iusto itaque distinctio quis blanditiis. Ad quos, voluptate labore aut aspernatur vitae nostrum quaerat
                quasi nulla earum incidunt facere dolorum ipsam necessitatibus ex illum hic voluptatibus! Suscipit laborum consectetur numquam neque ratione ullam asperiores adipisci quidem, totam praesentium nisi quisquam at tempora autem earum iste,
                itaque
                minima. Modi repellendus laudantium quas odio tempora hic similique molestias quia sapiente saepe nobis, vel, nemo impedit delectus. Voluptatum suscipit est, autem laborum, maiores ad nesciunt necessitatibus in neque sunt, ipsam dolorem
                rem.
                Sit, illum, non.
              </p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="process">
        <div class="bg1>
          <div class=" our_process">
          <a name="#process">
            <p>
              <h1>OUR PROCESS</h1>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ducimus officia vero, animi dicta magni tenetur praesentium quisquam, iusto itaque distinctio quis blanditiis. Ad quos, voluptate labore aut aspernatur vitae nostrum quaerat
              quasi nulla earum incidunt facere dolorum ipsam necessitatibus ex illum hic voluptatibus! Suscipit laborum consectetur numquam neque ratione ullam asperiores adipisci quidem, totam praesentium nisi quisquam at tempora autem earum iste,
              itaque
              minima. Modi repellendus laudantium quas odio tempora hic similique molestias quia sapiente saepe nobis, vel, nemo impedit delectus. Voluptatum suscipit est, autem laborum, maiores ad nesciunt necessitatibus in neque sunt, ipsam dolorem
              rem.
              Sit, illum, non.
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="portfolio">
        <div class="bg1">
          <div class="our_portfolio">
            <a name="#portfolio">
              <p>
                <h1>OUR PORTFOLIO</h1>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima ducimus officia vero, animi dicta magni tenetur praesentium quisquam, iusto itaque distinctio quis blanditiis. Ad quos, voluptate labore aut aspernatur vitae nostrum quaerat
                quasi nulla earum incidunt facere dolorum ipsam necessitatibus ex illum hic voluptatibus! Suscipit laborum consectetur numquam neque ratione ullam asperiores adipisci quidem, totam praesentium nisi quisquam at tempora autem earum iste,
                itaque
                minima. Modi repellendus laudantium quas odio tempora hic similique molestias quia sapiente saepe nobis, vel, nemo impedit delectus. Voluptatum suscipit est, autem laborum, maiores ad nesciunt necessitatibus in neque sunt, ipsam dolorem
                rem.
                Sit, illum, non.
              </p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      </section>
      <section id="footer">
        <footer>
          2020 DeborahPalmTree
        </footer>
      </section>
      <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}


#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(219, 219, 219, 1.0);
  position: fixed;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 20px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.bg1 {
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

/*.wrapper{
  width:50px;
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
    opacity:0;
    z-index:1;}
}*/

#main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('structural-images/img_house_trees.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
}

#about {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('structural-images/img_construction_site.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
}

#process {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('structural-images/img_arc_plan.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
}

#portfolio {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('structural-images/img-structure-garden-car-park.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
}

 #fixed{
   position: fixed;
   height :50px;
   width:100%;
   background-color: rgba(219,219,219,1.0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not use the id selector to reference the footer section in your css page, probably you referenced #fixed in place of footer instead, at the bottom of your CSS file.

// use this instead

```
 #footer{
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height :50px;
 width:100%;
 background-color: transparent;
```

}

You used the same selector on your menu nav, sections and subdivs (#portfiolio),you need to learn how to create layout properly and make use of css selectors properly. you can learn for free on udemy introduction to web design. Their explanation is very good, and also Kenvin Powell introduction to css course on Youtube.

For a quick fix 
Get one parent div with 2 children

```
<div class="parentDiv">
   <div class="bgDiv"></div>
   <div class="contentDiv></div>
</div>
```

you can play with the units to get your desired output, assuming the current screen size is 746px

```
.parentDiv{
   width: 646px;
   max-width: 100%;
      position: relative;
   max-width: 100%;
   margin: auto;
   perspective: 500px;
   height: 100%;

 }
.bgDiv{
      box-shadow: inset -3px -70px 8px 6vw rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
   background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(245, 242, 242, 0.44), rgba(255, 
    255, 255, 0.5)), url(https://placebear.com/500/300);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: -999;
    background-size: cover;

}
 .contentDiv{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50px;
  transform: translate3d(25px, 25px, 50px);
  padding: 4rem;

}
```

Comment: Hello Chukwuemeka, thank you so much for the recommendations I would really like to work on the layout and css selector knowledge you talked about but I do not really understand what you mean by I used same selector I used #main #about #process #portfolio for the different plus I really would like to set the background images with fixing it in the sections.please shed more light on the selector and bad layout you mentioned.